# Memory leak in Java (Wikipedia)

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I am trying to understand under which circumstances I would make **Memory Leaks** in my programs so I have started to read about that starting with  [This Wikipedia page](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speicherleck) written in German.

There is it an example written in Java at the bottom of the page:

```
 private static List<Integer> nummern = new ArrayList<>();
 public void erzeugeSpeicherleck() {
     for (int i=1; i<10000; i++)
     nummern.add(i);
 }
 // kein weiterer lesender Zugriff auf die List nummern (German)
 // no further read access to list 'nummern' (English)
```

I wrote this in JavaScript and everything worked fine.

```
var array = [];
for(var i=1; i<10000;i++){
    array.push(i);
    console.log(array);
}
```

Can somebody explain me why that piece of code in Java is producing a **Memory Leak** ?

Comment: You know the difference between JavaScript and Java, don't you? They are fundamentally different languages which only share part of the name. Besides that the comment line translates to "no further read access to list 'nummern'" - it is still possible to access the list :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java does load classes when needed but it does never unload a class.

Therefore if you save data in a static field like `nummern` in your example the field exists as long as the class is loaded. 
The garbage collector can also not collect the ArrayList stored in this field as it is still referenced by the field.

As the class is never unloaded the memory used by the field (or to be concrete in this case the ArrayList instance that is referenced by the field) is never freed.

Comment: Thank you . In conclusion i have to understand also how Java works

Answer (score 1):

`nummern` is static, so it'll be not cleaned by garbage collector.

There is no garbage collector in javascript. And `array` in your js function is not static.